# Experience Profile not showing all Contacts

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, experience-profile

I am running a JMeter test to create 10 different contacts in xDB. I can see them in xDB but when I come to Experience Profile dashboard I can see only 3 known records from JMeter and rest are all '**anonymous**' (old records).

Question:

- Any idea why would it show only 3 known records and not the other 7?
- Is there a way I can change the the xProfile dashboard to see more records? I think the default value is 20.

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Comment: The actual list of contacts, in the UI, is coming from the Sitecore_Reportiing MS-SQL database while the data is coming from the xDB. Can you look in xDB with a tool like Robo Mongo and see 10 records are created in Mongo? Also are there any errors in the logs that could be relevant?

Comment: Can you check if it has something to deal with robot detection? https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/robot_detection/configure_the_robot_detection_component You can try to temporary disable it (see section "Disabling robot detection" of the above article) and see how it goes?

Comment: Please attach the JMeter script you're using.

Comment: Did you find the reason why contacts were not shown? Have you managed to increase the number of contacts visible in xProfile dashboard?

Comment: can you add an interaction to your contact and check if it appear in xprofile?

Comment: Did you added the details in PersonalInformation facet? Also please check if there is any error in logs.

Comment: Yes.After adding interaction to a contact it's showing in Xprofile. Thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did you try refreshing your reporting database? https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database

sometime you see contacts in XDB but its not present in your SQL analytics database and thats when you may need to refresh the reporting DB so that all entries are updated in the reporting DB

Comment: Yes thats right, it was the refresh of reporting database that was needed

Comment: @Mohit can you mark my comment as answer then please?

Comment: I'd like to advocate thay this is the brute force answer to get your contacts to show. There can be other reasons for a delay in processing and aggregation, including an improper CD configuration. Rebuilding the reporting databse is simply covering up a potentially larger issue.

Comment: AFAIK experience profile uses analytics_index (which gets updated when rebuilding the reporting database) and not the sql db.

Answer (score 1):

Is your JMeter Script running from a single machine ? If you don't clear your cookies between runs then the traffic from your JMeter script may be being detected as the same user and combined together

Answer (score 1):

The contacts doesn't appear in the Experience Profile because a contact without interactions or event is considered anonymous. By default xConnect will not index and display anonymous contacts.

You have two options:

1. To add an interaction to the contact.
2. Enable indexing of anonymous contacts ( https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts.html )